# Spark RDD access restrictions and location within the cluster

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, mesos, access-rights

I have a question regarding RDD access control.

There is a data which has to be kept only at the given server(or list of them), no raw data is allowed to leave it. The data can be process by some `map` function and only after that can be transferred further.

**Are there any features in Spark or in supported cluster management solutions (e.g. Mesos)?**

Answer (score 1):

A `HadoopRDD` (used by `sc.textFile` for example) has an affinity to be located on the machine that has the file data. (See [`HadoopRDD.getPreferredLocations`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/HadoopRDD.scala#L292).) `map` is performed on the same machine then.

But this does not guarantee that the raw data will not leave the machine. If the Spark worker on the machine dies, for example, then another worker will load it from a different machine.

I think the safe option is to run one Spark cluster (or other processing system) on the "secure" machines, perform the `map` step in this cluster, and write out the result to the HDFS (or other storage system) running on the "unsecure" machines. Then a separate Spark cluster running on the "unsecure" machines can process the data.